# How to add layer to ultrachart for selection

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I have ultrachart on infragistics which shows 1 hour real time data.

I want to select any time on x-axis using cursor like below;

[image]

Currently I can select the datapoints. no problem with that.

However i need to draw rectangle with my mouse and select the datapoints between rectangle borders.

I am kind of helpless because i searched a lot but  didn't see similar things on the internet.

How can i make this happen ? I need your knowledge.

Comment: Have you tried to check out [Infragrastic forum](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-windows-forms/92075/how-to-ultrachart-highlight-selected-series)?

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes, a lot. I also asked the infragistic team. However they couldn't make it.

Comment: Official documentation refers to: [SetClipBounds(Rectangle) Method](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinChart.v11.2~Infragistics.UltraChart.Core.Primitives.GraphicsContext~SetClipBounds(Rectangle).html). I hope this helps...

Comment: Can you add some code of what have you done? Or at least what is the diagram's class name you are fighting with?